# Using Reactive Extensions to stream model changes

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am working on a server component which is responsible for caching models in memory and then stream any changes to interested clients.

When the first client requests a model (well model key, each model has a key to identify it) the model will be created (along with any subscriptions to downstream systems) and then sent to the client, followed by a stream of updates (generated by downstream systems).  Any subsequent client's should get this cached (updated) model, again with the stream of updates.  When the last client unsubscribes to the model the downstream subscriptions should be destroyed and the cached model destroyed.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as regards to how Rx could help here.  I guess what isn't clear to me at the moment is how I synchronize state (of the object) and the stream of changes?  Would I have two separate IObservables for the model and updates?

Update: here's what I have so far:

```
        Model model = null;

        return Observable.Create((IObserver<ModelUpdate> observer) =>
        {
            model = _modelFactory.GetModel(key);
            _backendThing.Subscribe(model, observer.OnNext);
            return Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                _backendThing.Unsubscribe(model);
            });
        })
            .Do((u) => model.MergeUpdate(u))
            .Buffer(_bufferLength)
            .Select(inp => new ModelEvent(inp))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount()
            .StartWith(new ModelEvent(model)
```

Comment: If there is going to be one model object and the object's lifetime is long then I would suggest that each Model encapsulates an Observable that would stream the changes.

Comment: Well there would be many model objects.  Ideally I'd like a way that something could subscribe to all model updates or a specific model's updates

Comment: @nzyme In your latest code example, instead of using `StartWith`, simply call `observer.OnNext(new ModelUpdate(model))` **before** subscribing to `_backendThing`.

Comment: @nzyme Also, closing over a variable in `Observable.Create` is a code smell.  In your particular case, it's technically not problematic because you're using `Publish().RefCount()`, though I'd probably avoid it anyway if possible.  For example, ModelUpdate should expose a Model property, or if you can't do that then define a struct like: `struct ModelNotification { ModelUpdate Update { get; } Model Model { get; } }`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, there are `Models` coming in dynamically. At any point in time in your Application's lifetime, the number of Models are unknown.

For that purpose an `IObservable<IEnumerable<Model>>` looks like a way to go. Each time there is a new Model added or an existing one removed, the updated `IEnumerable<Model>` would be streamed. Now it would essentially preserve the older objects as opposed to creating all Models each time there is an update unless there is a good reason to do so.

As for the update on each `Model` object's state such as any field value or property value changed, I would look into Paul Betts' `ReactiveUI` project, it has something called `ReactiveObject`. Reactive object helps you get change notifications easily, but that library is mainly designed for WPF MVVM applications.

Here is how a Model's state update would go with ReactiveObject

```
public class Model : ReactiveObject
{
  int _currentPressure;
  public int CurrentPressure
 {
   get { return _currentPressure; }
   set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChagned(ref _currentPressure, value); }
 }
}
```

now anywhere you have Model object in your application you could easily get an Observable that will give you updates about the object's pressure component. I can use `When` or `WhenAny` extension methods.

You could however not use ReactiveUI and have a simple IObservable whenever a state change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, though your requirements aren't exactly clear to me.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Key, IObservable<Model>> cache = new...

...

public IObservable<Model> GetModel(Key key)
{
   return cache.GetOrAdd(key, CreateModelWithUpdates);
}

private IObservable<Model> CreateModelWithUpdates(Key key)
{
   return Observable.Using(() => new Model(key), model => GetUpdates(model).StartWith(model))
                    .Publish((Model)null)
                    .RefCount()
                    .Where(model => model != null);
}

private IObservable<Model> GetUpdates(Model model) { ... }

...

public class Model : IDisposable
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, that was really helpful.  I think this is really close to what I want, but I need the StartWith after the publish so each subscriber gets the initial model.  I've updated my question with my latest code.  Unfortunately the StartWith seems to happen before the model initialization above it.

Comment: @nzyme Yes, my query doesn't generate an initial value (it was accidental though - I simply didn't test it).  I'm not going to correct it unless you need me to since I have a simple fix for your new code, which I'll post as a comment.